# How do I build an llvm-pass and then use clang to load the generated shared library in another rule?

Tags: c++, bazel

I have the following project structure:

```
llvm-pass/
  CMakeLists.txt
  BUILD
program/
  main.cc
  BUILD
WORKSPACE
```

In llvm-pass/BUILD

```
cmake_external(
  name="llvm-pass",
  output="llvm-pass.so"
)
```

In program/BUILD

```
cc_binary(
  name="program",
  srcs = ["main.cc"],
  copts = ["-Xclang -load ???"],
  data = ["//llvm-pass"]
)
```

I don't know how to determine the path of the llvm-pass object so that I may pass it as an argument to the program compilation rule. Any ideas?

Comment: `data` is not what you want. That will allow the compiled binary to access the file at runtime, not the compilation command. [cc_binary.copts](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.copts) says it allows variable expansion, so `copts = ["-Xclang", "-load", "$(execpath //llvm-pass)"]` is kind of close, but you still need to make that label accessible somehow. additional_linker_inputs can do it for linking, but I don't see a way to do it for compilation.

Comment: I spent a few hours trying to figure this out and the only solution I could come up with is writing a genrule that created the shared library for the llvm pass and copied it to /tmp/ then using that as my argument in Copts. Bazel allows the use of .so as a source dependency. However, it only makes the shared library available at link time, not compile time. I tried coercing it into making the shared library available earlier by generating a .h file and depending on that, but that didn’t seem to work. I haven’t tried generating the pass without the .so extension.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`cc_import`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_import)?